# Wordpress Theme issues

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So i currently developing some Wordpress Theme nothing special. I ran into a problem another day. The problem goes like this, when I add the following code to the header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/reset.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css">
```

everything works fine, but when i make the following chages

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/reset.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

i get an error that the template missing.

Comment: This is the wrong way to include stylesheets. You should be using `wp_enqueue_style()`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to include stylesheet files is with the enqueue_style function.

go to your theme's functions.php file and search for: `function themename_enqueue_style()`

```
function themename_enqueue_style() {

    /* Past the wp_enqueue_style() below in this function */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/reset.css', false);

}
/* Don't forget Add_action below the function */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: You're missing an `add_action()`. This is a custom developed theme, so that function likely doesn't exist at all in *functions.php*.

Comment: Eddited my answer.. For more examples visit -->  [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Answer (score 0):

In a standard WordPress installation, the two statements would refer to different locations.

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>
```

would return "yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/active_theme/style.css".

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/style.css
```

would be "yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/active_theme/css/style.css".

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/reset.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```